# How can you right align or decimal align numbers using the rails datagrid gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to use the datagrid gem in a project. I want to have a numeric column right aligned and can't seem to do that.

My admin_plans_grid.rb is

```
class AdminPlansGrid < BaseGrid

  scope do
    Plan
  end

  filter(:id, :integer)
  filter(:created_at, :date, :range => true)
  filter(:plan_type)

  column(:id)
  column(:name)
  column(:term)
  column(:cost) do 
    style="text-align:right"
    self.cost
  end
  column(:plan_type)
  date_column(:created_at)
  column(:actions, html: true) do |model|
  # link_to "Show", admin_plan 
end
end
```

I've been trying variations on the cost column such as what is shown above

```
   column(:cost) do 
    style="text-align:right"
    self.cost
  end
```

I've tried span and a few other ideas but nothing worked.

Question - How can I get the data in the cost column to right or decimal align?

Comment: can you show us html of that column in browser?

Answer (score 1):

Okay here is solution, you can override a table td class value like this:
in file: `datagrid-demo/app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.sass`
add this for a column disabled or any other you needs align

```
table.users_grid
  td, th 
    &.disabled
      text-align: right
```

This is how it looks on my env:

[image]

[image]